# How to fix HTTPS on express-gateway

Tags: https, microservices, express-gateway

I'm running a micro-service API, and I use express-gateway. This API has been running since 1 years. I need to implement HTTPS connection to it, and I have difficulties to do.

I've generated SSL certificate thanks to openssl. I have server keys and clients key.

I've configurate my gateway this way `gateway.config.yml`:

```yaml
http:
 port: 8000

https:
  port: 9443
  hostname: localhost
  tls:
    "default":
        key: ‘path/to/server.key'
        cert: 'path/to/server.crt'

admin:
  port: 9876
  host: localhost
apiEndpoints:
  api:
    host: '*'
    paths: '/ip'
  test:
    host: '*'
    paths: ['/test', '/test/*']
  voice:
    host: '*'
    paths: ['/voices', '/voices/*']
serviceEndpoints:
  httpbin:
    url: 'https://httpbin.org'
  testService:
    url: 'http://localhost:6969'
  voiceService:
    url: 'http://localhost:6965'
policies:
  - basic-auth
  - cors
  - expression
  - key-auth
  - log
  - oauth2
  - proxy
  - rate-limit
pipelines:
  default:
    apiEndpoints:
      - api
    policies:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: httpbin
              changeOrigin: true
  testPipeline:
    apiEndpoints:
      - test
    policies:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: testService
              changeOrigin: true
  voicePipeline:
    apiEndpoints:
      - voice
    policies:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: voiceService
              changeOrigin: true
```

and here is my `voice-service.js` :

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const middleware = require('./middleware/index');
const firebase = require('./config/firebase-config');
const { spawn, execSync } = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();
const port = 6965;
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
app.use(express.json({limit: '100mb'}));

app.use(cors());

app.use(middleware.decodeToken);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to the Voice API');
})

app.get('/voices', async (req, res) => {
    ...
});

app.post('/voices', jsonParser, async (req, res) => {
    ...
});

app.delete('/voices', async (req, res) => {
    ...
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

My API use firebase bearers tokens and have a middleware to check it validity `middleware.js` :

```js
const admin = require('../config/firebase-config');

class Middleware {
    async decodeToken(req, res, next) {
        try {
            const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
            const decodeValue = await admin.admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);
            if (decodeValue)
                return next();
            return res.json({ message: 'Invalid Token' });
        } catch (e) {
            return res.json({ message: 'Invalid Token' });
        }
    }
}
module.exports = new Middleware();
```

When I tried to test https, I tried with Postman. I added my client ssl key into it and a valid bearer token. I tried to get the 'voices/' route. With http method it's working fine, but with https it's always result timeout.

Could anyone help me?
I tried to be as exhaustive as I can but if you need more informations, ask it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the testService and voiceService URLs in serviceEndpoints list from

```
serviceEndpoints:
  httpbin:
    url: 'https://httpbin.org'
  testService:
    url: 'http://localhost:6969'
  voiceService:
    url: 'http://localhost:6965'
```

to use https:

```
serviceEndpoints:
  httpbin:
    url: 'https://httpbin.org'
  testService:
    url: 'https://localhost:6969'
  voiceService:
    url: 'https://localhost:6965'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix my problem. HTTP responds are now 'Bad gateway.' and HTTPS still timeout.

Comment: This can't work, the HTTPS handcheck must be done only once, and as it's done by the gateway, the redirection have to be http.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of investigations, it turns out I simply forgot to open my port. This project is self hosted.

I also need to change `gateway.config.yml` https part :

```yaml
https:
  port: 9443
  hostname: localhost
  tls:
    "default":
        key: ‘path/to/server.key'
        cert: 'path/to/server.crt'
```